# Unable to fetch mapping Do you have indices matching the pattern?

Tags: windows, elasticsearch, logstash, kibana, nxlog

I followed this tutorial to get it all installed on my machine. The machine I installed everything on is windows server 2008, and I am remoting into it from my windows 7 computer.

https://www.ulyaoth.net/resources/tutorial-install-logstash-and-kibana-on-a-windows-server.34/

From what I can gather, there is no information being shipped to elasticearch yet. I'm not really sure if its a problem with my nxlog/logstash setup or my network settings. I've already opened all the appropriate ports. Can someone help me troubleshoot this issue? Let me know if you need anything else. Thanks!

When I check and see if elasticsearch is running with localhost:9200 I get:

```
{
  "status" : 200,
  "name" : "Electro",
  "cluster_name" : "elasticsearch",
  "version" : {
    "number" : "1.7.2",
    "build_hash" : "e43676b1385b8125d647f593f7202acbd816e8ec",
    "build_timestamp" : "2015-09-14T09:49:53Z",
    "build_snapshot" : false,
    "lucene_version" : "4.10.4"
  },
  "tagline" : "You Know, for Search"
}
```

Here is my logstash.conf and nxlog.conf files.

#### nxlog.conf

```
#define ROOT C:\Program Files\nxlog
define ROOT C:\Program Files (x86)\nxlog

Moduledir %ROOT%\modules
CacheDir %ROOT%\data
Pidfile %ROOT%\data\nxlog.pid
SpoolDir %ROOT%\data
LogFile %ROOT%\data\nxlog.log

<Extension json>
    Module xm_json
</Extension>
<Input iis_ELKstack>  
      Module    im_file
      File    "C:\inetpub\logs\LogFiles\W3SVC1\u_ex*.log"
    ReadFromLast True
    SavePos True
    Exec    if $raw_event =~ /^#/ drop();
</Input>  
<Output out_logstash>  
    Module  om_tcp
    Host    loghost.elkstack.net
    Port    5544
    OutputType  LineBased
</Output>  

<Route IIS>  
    Path    iis_ELKstack => out_logstash
</Route>
```

#### logstash.conf

```
input {
  tcp {
    port => 5544
  }
}

output {
  elasticsearch {
    host => "loghost.elkstack.net"
    protocol => "http"
  }
}
```

Comment: im also stuck in this. Any update on this?